# Writing .php file using php code

Tags: php

Hi there I'm trying to write a .php file using this code, server replying this error : **syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER) in**
I wanna know how can I write integer in php file as you can see

> **$status1 =    \''0'\';**

This code having problem, anybody please tell me what to do.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user1'])){

$data =  urldecode('%3C').'?php

$user1 = \''.$_POST['user1'].'\';
$pass1 = \''.$_POST['pass1'].'\';
$status1 = \''0'\';
$user2 = \''.$_POST['user2'].'\';
$pass2 = \''.$_POST['pass2'].'\';
$status2 = \''0'\';
$user3 = \''.$_POST['user3'].'\';
$pass3 = \''.$_POST['pass3'].'\';
$status3 = \''0'\';
$user4 = \''.$_POST['user4'].'\';
$pass4 = \''.$_POST['pass4'].'\';
$status4 = \''0'\';
$user5 = \''.$_POST['user5'].'\';
$pass5 = \''.$_POST['pass5'].'\';
$status5 = \''0'\';
$user6 = \''.$_POST['user6'].'\';
$pass6 = \''.$_POST['pass6'].'\';
$status6 = \''0'\';
$user7 = \''.$_POST['user7'].'\';
$pass7 = \''.$_POST['pass7'].'\';
$status7 = \''0'\';
$user8 = \''.$_POST['user8'].'\';
$pass8 = \''.$_POST['pass8'].'\';
$status8 = \''0'\';
$user9 = \''.$_POST['user9'].'\';
$pass9 = \''.$_POST['pass9'].'\';
$status9 = \''0'\';
$user10 = \''.$_POST['user10'].'\';
$pass10 = \''.$_POST['pass10'].'\';
$status10 = \''0'\';

?'.urldecode('%3E');

$fx=fopen('datauser.php','w');
fwrite($fx,$data);
fclose($fx);

if($fx === false) {
   header("Location: ./tokensettings.php?save=err");
}
else {

    header("Location: ./tokensettings.php?save=success");
}
}   


?>
```

Thank you so much.

Here is how my form looks like.

[image]

Comment: you need to stop doing everything you're doing... this makes zero sense

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: completely agree with @NDM, the php is invalid in places, but there are better ways to code what you are doing rather than writing out each user pass and status that many times

Comment: Ahan! what is the better way to do that? can you please elaborate. I am old buddy in php learned a long time ago.

Comment: You have the concatenation wrong: `$status1 = \'' . 0 . '\';`

However I agree with NDM, whatever you are doing (I have no idea - do you want to store some data? Use database!), there is surely a better way.

Comment: I dont wanna use database, I love to do with file handling!

Comment: Check the ss I've updated, that's what I wanna do.

Comment: I dont want anyone to register mate! that's for my personal use.

Comment: Yep no idea what you are doing!  Looks like maybe urlencode a username that contains @ symbol but you are just displaying so why urlencode?  Maybe provide a couple of sample strings that you want to parse, echo, process or whatever with desired output.

Comment: OK I think I understand you are trying to use php to write ph - sorry bit slow on the uptake there - give a short example of the code you want to write

Comment: creating a PHP-file with user-input - especially completely unfiltered - is not just a security risk, but IMHO borderline criminally insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do it your way you need to use the \ correctly for each ' to be included in the string even those in [ ] - not saying the final string produced would actually work but it is based on your code and my best guess at your desired result

```
<?php 
$string1=' \'\'.$_POST[\'user1\']\'\';';
$string1=$string1.'\'\'0\'\';';
echo $string1;

?>
```

Comment: in what universe is this a correct answer? xD this makes even less sense than the question

Comment: @NDM - He wanted to use php to write php code and was getting an error in his code - I explained why he was getting the error and gave an example of the correct syntax based on his code with a short example script to demonstrate - and the asker marked it as correct because it solved his problem

Comment: your code will output `''.$_POST['user1']'';` which is a syntax error. not to mention all those escaped quotes are useless anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The whole `urlencoding` stuff is not needed at all, your quoting and escaping is messy and incorrect. and why not simply use `file_put_contents`? Use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid messy escaping.

```
file_put_contents('datauser.php', <<<CONTENT
<?php

\$user = '{$_POST['user']}';
\$pass = '{$_POST['pass']}';
\$status = '0';
CONTENT
);
```

but if you really want to use files as data storage, I would encourage you to save it in a data format like `xml` or `json` instead of writing php.

```
// save data to file ($_POST used as example...)
file_put_contents('user.json', json_encode($_POST));

// read data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('user.json'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. buddy that helped me.